# When Data mine is triggered, if the runner survives this ice, can (s)he/other still continue?

Tags: android-netrunner

Let's say we have the following setup in this order: 
1) ICE: [Data mine.](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=data%20mine) 
2) Asset: [Melange Mining Corp.](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=melange)

That is I have a remote server, which consists of 1 ice and 1 asset.

The Runner encounters the ICE. The runner loses 1 card, and survives the encounter.

Since there is no 'End the run' subroutine, can the runner continue to access the asset once I trash the ice? ( according to the rule of this ICE, I have to trash the ice once the subroutine fires )

Thanks, 
Suman

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Core rules:

> After the Runner breaks all of the ice’s subroutines and/or any
>   effects from unbroken subroutines resolve without ending the run, he
>   has passed that piece of ice. He then continues the run by either
>   approaching the next piece of ice protecting the server or proceeding
>   to the Access phase if there is no more ice to approach.

Data Mine doesn't end the run, so the run continues.  In you example, the runner would go on to access Melange Mining Corp.

It trashes itself as part of its ability because trap ice cards are designed to be hard to break but only hit once.